# Does the bounds of a uiview change when a pinch gesture is used on it?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to expand/reduce a uiview.

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleElement:)];
[pinchGesture setDelegate:self];
[element addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[pinchGesture release];
```

//Scale element method

```
- (void)scaleElement:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView *element = [gestureRecognizer view];
    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        lastTouchPosition = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:element];
    } 
    else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
            CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:element];
            CGPoint deltaMove = [self calculatePointDistancewithPoint1:currentTouchPosition andPoint2:lastTouchPosition];
            float distance = sqrt(deltaMove.x*deltaMove.x + deltaMove.y*deltaMove.y);
            float hScale = 1 - deltaMove.x/distance * (1-gestureRecognizer.scale);
            float vScale = 1 - deltaMove.y/distance * (1-gestureRecognizer.scale);
            if (distance == 0) {
                hScale = 1;
                vScale = 1;
            }
            element.transform = CGAffineTransformScale([element transform], hScale, vScale);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(hScale, vScale);
            element.bounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(element.bounds, transform);
                [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
                lastTouchPosition = currentTouchPosition;
            }
            if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                NSLog(@"scaling over");
                NSLog(@"bounds = %@",NSStringFromCGRect(element.bounds));
                NSLog(@"frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect(element.frame));
            }
            NSLog(@"scalePiece exit");
    }

//adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer method

    - (void)adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            UIView *elementToAdjust = gestureRecognizer.view;
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:gestureRecognizer.view];
            CGPoint locationInView = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:elementToAdjust];
            CGPoint locationInSuperview = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:elementToAdjust.superview];
            elementToAdjust.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / elementToAdjust.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / elementToAdjust.bounds.size.height);
            elementToAdjust.center = locationInSuperview;
        }
    }
```

Console print:

```
bounds = {{0, 0}, {178.405, 179.018}}
frame = {{300.642, 566.184}, {192.899, 194.227}}
```

Why isn't the bounds adjusting when the frame is changing ?
Does it have anything to do with auto resizing masks as I have subviews to this view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. This has everything to do with your setting the `transform` to perform scaling. Changing the `transform` does not change `bounds`. It just changes how this view's coordinate space (`bounds`) maps to the superview's coordinate space (`frame`). If you need `bounds` to match `frame`, you have to change one of them directly, not use `transform`. That said, you should generally use `transform` because it's much faster.

**EDIT**

If you don't mean to scale, but rather mean to resize the view, call `setBounds:`.  You can find the new `bounds` by applying the transform to the `bounds` rather than the element.

```
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:element];
CGPoint deltaMove = [self calculatePointDistancewithPoint1:currentTouchPosition andPoint2:lastTouchPosition];
...

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(hScale, vScale);
self.bounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.bounds, transform);
```

Comment: So how do you suggest I go about changing the bounds of the view ?

Comment: gestureRecognizer does not have a property transform. Do you mean [gestureRecognizer view].transform ?

Comment: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(). fixed.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. After doing this, the frame and bounds are still not the same. I am updating the question. Please look into it.

Comment: You're still setting `element.transform`. You shouldn't be if you're also setting `bounds`.

Comment: Perfect. Stupid of me not to think of that on my own. Thanks.